# Asp.net core 2.0 TLS 1.2 exception "The client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, tls1.2, nopcommerce-4.1

Let me list specs regarding this application:

- Windows 10 for all of us
- Asp.net core 2.0 web app
- We all use VS2017
- We're using IIS Express
- SSL is turned on for this application
- We trust our IIS express localhost cert

During startup we do the following:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

The problem we're having is only happening to some of our team members in their localhost environment.

In a background task thread, we use the `System.Net.WebClient` to make a call to a different URL of our app (again, to localhost), but it results in an  exception whose innermost exception message is

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

We know that setting `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` fixes the problem but we need it to remain at `Tls12`.

This must be a setting in either IIS Express or a firewall setting or something else environmental.

Some posts on Google suggest that we install .NET 4.6+ but we all have it installed already, so that's not it.

Comment: `only happening to some of our team members`  So.. rebuild their environments?

Comment: Do you mean reinstall iis or something more drastic like reinstall an image on their machine? Because since we've been supporting multiple applications for some time I don't think the latter is an option, we're hoping it's just something like a setting in IIS Express or something

Comment: What operating systems are in play? Particularly among the developers it's not working for?

Comment: Windows 10 for all of us.

Comment: does the accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521305/iis-express-getting-ssl-to-work help?

Comment: It does not, in VS the project is already set to Enable SSL and all of us can hit it from a browser using https. The problem only happens when a background task (like a keep-alive task) uses WebClient to call into itself: the WebClient throws an exception.

Comment: Not sure if it's acceptable for you, but did you try to use multiple values for ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property. Something like this: ```ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls | Tls11 | Tls12;```